# How do I build a PPAPI plugin on Linux?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I build a PPAPI plugin for Chromium on Linux?

For example, I want to build the stub example provided by the project. http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/ppapi/examples/stub/stub.cc?view=markup

So far I have the following Makefile

```
libexample.so.1.0.1:example.o
    g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libexample.so.1 -o libexample.so.1.0.1 example.o -lc -lppapi_cpp -lppapi_cpp_objects -L /home/carlos/Desktop/ppapi/example/

example.o:
    g++ -fPIC -Wall -g -c stub.cc -o example.o -I /home/carlos/Desktop/

clean:
    rm example.o libexample.so.1.0.1

run:
    google-chrome -d --register-pepper-plugins="/home/carlos/Desktop/ppapi/examples/stub/libexample.so.1.0.1;application/x-ppapi-example"
```

However, libexample.so.1.0.1 is missing symbols.

```
nm libexample.so.1.0.1 --demangle -u | grep pp::
```

Gives me this:

```
U pp::Module::Get()
U typeinfo for pp::Module
U typeinfo for pp::Instance
```

**Where are those symbols?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that

> make -n

allows one to reproduce what a complicated Makefile is doing. From there, it was a matter of some trial and error. Below is the Makefile that works for me.

```
libppapi_example.so:stub.o
    g++ -shared  -pthread -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-soname=libppapi_example.so -o libppapi_example.so -Wl,--start-group stub.o libppapi_cpp.a libppapi_cpp_objects.a -Wl,--end-group 

stub.o:
    g++  '-DNO_HEAPCHECKER' '-DCHROMIUM_BUILD' '-DENABLE_REMOTING=1' '-DENABLE_GPU=1' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1' '-D_DEBUG' -I/home/carlos/Desktop/chromium/src/ -Werror -pthread -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility=hidden -O0 -g -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -MMD -MF stub.o.d.raw -c -o stub.o stub.cc

clean:
    rm -f stub.o.d.raw stub.o libppapi_example.so

run:
    google-chrome -d --register-pepper-plugins="/home/carlos/Desktop/ppapi/examples/stub/libppapi_example.so;application/x-ppapi-example"
```

Comment: I am trying to implement a trusted plugin and want to use the C++ API of Pepper (right now I am stuck to version 16). Can someone tell me where I can find the libraries "libppapi_cpp.a libppapi_cpp_objects.a"? The "libppap_cpp.a" is contained in the NACL-SDK crosscompile-folders for newlib and glibc... but from what I understood these crosscompile-environments are only used for NaCl-modules. Can someone point me into the right direction? (When using the C-API you don't have to link against any libs... so my plugin does work with C-API... but I want to use the C++ API). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Superfisi sounds like a new question. Perhaps you would have more success getting an answer that way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. At first I also thought about entering it as a new question... but then I thought since you have the "-lppapi_cpp -lppapi_cpp_objects" in your Makefile you maybe can help me out where to get these two.

Comment: @Superfisi, I worked on this a year ago. I have no recollection of how it worked and I'm sure it has changed in a years time.