# How to set up Linker Flags when developing Google Pepper Trusted Plugin with C++ API

Tags: c++, c, google-chrome, google-nativeclient

**Hi everyone,**

I am trying to build a Chromium Trusted Plugin (no sandboxed NaCl-Plugin) using the Pepper API (version 16) on Linux. "Trusted Plugin" means that I am passing the path to my Plugin when starting Chrome, the Plugin get's loaded in context of a specific, custom application-type.

Using the C-API everything works find because the Plugin then does not have to be linked against any Google-libraries. But when I am using the C++-API of Pepper some symbols are missing; demangled e.g...

`pp::Instance::Init(unsigned int, char const**, char const**)`)

... but I simply don't know which Libraries have to by linked to my Shared Library. Of course I downloaded the Pepper SDK, but all in there seems to be prepared for development of NaCl-Plugins and therefore crosscompiling (I don't have to crosscompile).

I tried to ask a followup-question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675661/how-do-i-build-a-ppapi-plugin-on-linux), because the issuer uses "-lppapi_cpp -lppapi_cpp_objects" in his Makefile, but he couldn't help.

**So my question is:** How do I have to set the linker flags? Or am I missing something else? Where to find the missing libraries?

*Thanks in advance and best regards!*

Answer (score 0):

Writing trusted PPAPI plugins is not encouraged. That's why there are no Pepper SDK. If you want to build a trusted plugin, you need to build chrome and take `libppapi_cpp.a` and `libppapi_cpp_objects.a` (possibly some more) libraries from `out/Debug/obj/ppapi` or `out/Release/obj/ppapi` directories.

Note, that untrusted PPAPI plugins can be associated with MIME types too.